# Non-Isometric of the Wolpert's problem

Tags: spectral-theory, isometry

Related to the document [Drums That Sound the Same](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2975346?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) of S. J. Chapman, he has proved those two shapes

[image]

was isopectrals.

**Question :** I don't know how to prove that they are not isometric (Riemannian isometry), and I didn't find out any references on the subject. Could anyone be able to prove in details that both shapes are not isometric?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The two vertices with acute angles are at distance $\sqrt{10}$ in the first, $\sqrt{2}$ in the second.

EDIT:

[image]

[image]

There are many other differences.  For example, the longest edge of the first polygon has length $2$, of the second $2 \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Could you put a little more details?

Comment: I am not sure about your explanation. So there not exists $f$ respecting the definition : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry_(Riemannian_geometry), why?

Comment: An isometry of a connected open set in Euclidean space is affine (a translation plus an orthogonal transformation)